# Caching Matplotlib with Memcache (Wont Pickle)

Tags: python, memcached, matplotlib, pickle

I have a chart that is rendered takes 3 seconds and then subcharts that can be made from said chart where things are added to it. I want to cache the axes from the main chart so that I can retrieve it and modify it later when rendering the subcharts. How can I get past this error?

Heres a sample test code:

```
import pylibmc
cache = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True})
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cache_name = 'test'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 7))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0.15, 0.98, 0.85])
cache.set(cache_name, ax, 300)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Is there anyway I could get this to work?

Comment: Is the data structure the part that take 3 seconds or the actual plot by matplotlib? There have been discussions about this before and apparently nothing has been done in terms of making matplotlib serializable.

Comment: Matplotlib Plotting. Since their candlestick plots suck, I am plotting a candlestick chart using individual bars. And since I cant get bar to work through a list (diff colors, values, error bars) I am adding each bar individually thorough a loop (about 400 items) which is likely causing it to take that long. Sample script here: http://pastebin.com/6aD8YZfM. If I could cache those final set of bars, the time wouldn't be that important.

Comment: So in that sample loop, the axis creation takes time? And you do that 400 times to produce a collection of axis that take 3 seconds?

Comment: Each time in that loop takes about .01 to .03s x 400 puts me at around  4-5 seconds to place all the bars on the image. Everything else is really quick. If I could either cache the collection of bars or speed up adding the bars (possibly adding them by batch) I'd be golden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are discussion out there regarding the desire for matplotlib figures to be able to be serialized. I haven't seen anything that reports this has been addressed or even accepted as a goal. So if you try to send them over the wire to memcached, its obviously going to fail. The discussions that I have found when searching suggest that the current design of matplotlib doesn't cater to this goal easily, and it would require a refactor of the internals. Reference: http://old.nabble.com/matplotlib-figure-serialization-td28016714.html

What you could do, to dramatically reduce your execution time, is to reorganize your data into a dataset, and only call `ax.bar()` once. The dataset can then be serialized and stored in whatever format you want (into memcached for instance).

Here is a code example showing the test between your approach, and one that combines them into a dataset. You can view it here more easily if you want: https://gist.github.com/2597804

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint 
from time import time 

DATA = [
    (i, randint(5,30), randint(5,30), randint(30,35), randint(1,5)) \
    for i in xrange(1, 401)
]

def mapValues(group):
    ind, open_, close, high, low = group
    if open_ > close: # if open is higher then close
        height = open_ - close # heigth is drawn at bottom+height
        bottom = close
        yerr = (open_ - low, high - open_)
        color = 'r' # plot as a white barr
    else:
        height = close - open_ # heigth is drawn at bottom+height
        bottom = open_
        yerr = (close - low, high - close)
        color = 'g' # plot as a black bar

    return (ind, height, bottom, yerr, color)

#
# Test 1
#
def test1():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    data = map(mapValues, DATA)

    start = time()

    for group in data: 

        ind, height, bottom, yerr, color = group

        ax.bar(left=ind, height=height, bottom=bottom, yerr=zip(yerr), 
                color=color, ecolor='k', zorder=10,
                error_kw={'barsabove': False, 'zorder': 0, 'capsize': 0}, 
                alpha=1)

    return time()-start

#
# Test 2
#
def test2():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # plotData can be serialized
    plotData = zip(*map(mapValues, DATA))

    ind, height, bottom, yerr, color = plotData

    start = time()

    ax.bar(left=ind, height=height, bottom=bottom, yerr=zip(*yerr), 
            color=color, ecolor='k', zorder=10,
            error_kw={'barsabove': False, 'zorder': 0, 'capsize': 0}, 
            alpha=1)

    return time()-start


def doTest(fn):
    end = fn()
    print "%s - Sec: %0.3f, ms: %0d" % (fn.__name__, end, end*1000)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    doTest(test1)
    doTest(test2)

    # plt.show()
```

Results:

```
python plot.py 
test1 - Sec: 1.592, ms: 1592
test2 - Sec: 0.358, ms: 357
```

Comment: Thank a bunch. The charting went from 5s to 1.7s thanks so much! Still hoping for a matplotlib caching mechanism in the long run!

Answer (score 1):

As of matplotlib 1.2 you should be able to pickle and unpickle figures.

This is very much an "experimental" feature, but if you do find any issues, please let us know on the mpl mailing list or by raising an issue on github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes), it would appear that `fig.add_axes()` takes a tuple as an argument, where you're passing a list. As such, it's not returning the `Axes` object (since it isn't being created), so ax is being assigned the function itself.

Comment: This is not correct. The various methods can take a sequence, be it a list or tuple. Either way. `add_axes()` is returning an `Axis` object. The problem is that the OP is trying to send the Axis instance across the wire to memcached, which wants to be able to serialize the object. matplotlib objects can't be serialized. Its basically choking on the various internals of the axis. Take a look at the value of `ax.__dict__`. You will see its a huge reference of other matplotlib objects, including the figure, etc.