# How to backup and restore python current working environment?

Tags: python, backup

I want to write a function `'backup(filename)'` to store all the working data (objects?) under current environment of Python, and `'restore(filename)'` to restore the data/object again. Just like R's `save.image(file="workspace21.RData")` and  `load(file="workspace21.RData")`, which can snapshot the system.

How to write the "backup" & "restore" ? Or is there any package existed can do that ?

Comment: You mean like [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: somewhat like pickle. I need it to pickle the whole workspace , but some of python objects are not_picklable, so I doubt pickle is the solution.

Comment: For example, matplotlib.figure.Figure object is not pickleable, cPickle.dump(fig, open("Z:\\pic.pkl",'w'), cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) will have TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

Comment: Hmm, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390521/caching-matplotlib-with-memcache-wont-pickle) which sounds related to trying to pickle matplotlib figures.  @pelson says version 1.2 should support pickling, but without trying it myself I can't comment.

Comment: matplotlib figure is only a sample, there might exists other kinds of not-picklable objects .

Answer (score 3):

pickle module seems like a solution but it cannot really save the whole environment for you. Try for example this:

```
import pickle

def backup(fileName):
    pickle.dump(globals(), open(fileName,'w'), pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def restore(fileName):
    globals().update(pickle.load(open(fileName,"rb")))
```

This will not work because module objects are not picklable. You will also have problems with open file descriptors and other objects. See answers on this question for (partial) solutions:

[How can I save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)

So, while you cannot have a general solution to your problem, you can write something which will save some of your (global) objects, using the snippet above as a starting point, if that helps.

Comment: One more issue for me is how to load the stored variable from pickled file to global() namespace by a function.  def restore(fileName): cPickle.load(open(fileName,"rb"))  seems not able to restore the variable back to global namespace .

Comment: You could do something like: globals().update(cPickle.load(open(fileName,"rb")))

Answer (score 3):

A bit out of the box, but if this is important and you really need a full solution, you can run python inside a virtual machine and use snapshots to save session state. Whether it is practical or not depends on your use case.

Comment: Good tip. Though it is a little bit heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on [pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). You also have [an example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example) that can help you to do what you're thinking on.